# TestBed overrideModule method seem to remove previously added providers

Tags: angular6, angular-test

Does `TestBed.overrideModule` replace previously added providers?

I have a `Component` `c1` which uses a dynamically created component `c2`. I read that I need to use `overrideModule` to add `entryComponents` entry in the `TestBed`.

So I did this

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ NewPracticeQuestionComponent,
  DialogBoxComponent,
    ShowErrorsComponent],
  imports:[ReactiveFormsModule,HttpClientTestingModule],
  providers:[WebToBackendInterfaceService,
    HelperService,
    AuthService,
    {provide:QuestionManagementService, useClass:MockQuestionManagementService}] //NOTE I HAVE A DIFFERENT PROVIDER HERE
});
TestBed.overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
  set: {
    entryComponents: [DialogBoxComponent]/*DialogBoxComponent is created dynamically (imperatively), soit nee to be ddded in entryComponent*/
    }
  });
TestBed.compileComponents();
```

Above, I have provided `MockQuestionManagementService` as different provider for `QuestionManagementService`. But I notice that when creating the component, `Angular` created `QuestionManagementService`!!

to fix the problem, I had to explicitly call `TestBed.overrideProvider`

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ NewPracticeQuestionComponent,
      DialogBoxComponent,
        ShowErrorsComponent],
      imports:[ReactiveFormsModule,HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers:[WebToBackendInterfaceService,
        HelperService,
        AuthService,
        {provide:QuestionManagementService, useClass:MockQuestionManagementService}]
    });
    TestBed.overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
      set: {
        entryComponents: [DialogBoxComponent]/*DialogBoxComponent is created dynamically (imperatively), soit nee to be ddded in entryComponent*/
        }
      });
    TestBed.overrideProvider(QuestionManagementService,{useValue: new MockQuestionManagementService},); //THIS ADDED EXPLICITLY
    TestBed.compileComponents();
  }));
```

Now `Angular` added the `MockQuestionManagementService`. Did I incorrectly use `overrideModule` or it is expected behaviour of `TestBed.overrideModule`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with `TestBed` but with the way I had configured the `providers`. I had used `@Injectable({  providedIn: 'root'})` in the service's `.ts` file rather than in module's `.ts`. So even if I configured the `TestModule` to use the provided configuration (`{provide:QuestionManagementService, useClass:MockQuestionManagementService}`), it seems it kept picking the instance of `QuestionManagementService` from the root injector unless I explicitly override it by calling `TestBed.overrideProvider(QuestionManagementService,{useValue: new MockQuestionManagementService},);`

Though I still wonder why the configuration provided to the `TestBed` didn't work. Isn't the lookup for dependencies from Component to Module to Root?